# Postgresql : Jdbc Bulk insert Vs. Hibernate Bulk Insert

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jdbc

I used Postgresql database for my web application.
on each day have to insert around 10 million of data to database.
there are 2 ways to insert into database

1. Bulk insert using JDBC (EX. `Insert into table(col1,col2) values((col1val1, col2val1),(col1val2, col2val2));`
2. Hibernate Bulk Insert

want to know which is fast and safer method to insert data?

Comment: What happened when you tried? Btw: what's an "ariund crore"?

Comment: write reason if downvoting...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd say it's lack of versions and that there's no sign you tried or researched before posting.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to bulk insert is to use `COPY`.

See the [jdbc documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html#copyIn%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29) and [server-side COPY command documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).